# Why use 1 instead of -1?

Tags: cpu

At 29min mark of http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/Writing-Quick-Code-in-Cpp-Quickly Andrei Alexandrescu says when using constants to prefer 0 and mentions hardware knows how to handle it. I did some assembly and I know what he is talking about and about the zero flag on CPUs

Then he says prefer the constant 1 rather then -1. -1 IIRC is not actually special but because it is negative the sign flag on CPUs would be set. 1 from my current understanding is simply a positive number there is no bit on the processor flag for it and no way to distinguish from 0 or other positive numbers.

But Andrei says to prefer 1 over -1. Why? What does hardware do with 1 that is better then -1?

Comment: Please write a complete question; most people will not go and watch 30 minutes of a linked video to see what the background to the question is. Specifically, I have no clue what you mean by "1 next", or "prefer" for what purpose.

Comment: i really like the question :D , maybe it is because of binary things!0 is 0 and 1 is 1 but -1 is some thing like 001010! i don't know!

Comment: Basically, he was speaking about it in optimization context, so ... -1 gets stored in memory as FFFF, so not only it will trigger, as you said, sign flag, but, performing operations with it might trigger overflow and few other flags, what, in return, would result in operations being handled in a bit different way, which then would waste more computational time.

Comment: @Tomas I seriously doubt that setting a flag to 1 is more expensive than setting a flag to 0.

Comment: @Amadan: Slight modified (first paragraph). Is it better?

Comment: @FredOverflow: He is talking about ints and using numbers as constants. Although he just showed a bitfield template he is just talking about ints and constant valeus. No bit setting incode. Just flipping bits on the processor state

Comment: @acidzombie24 I know. What I meant was: an addition that overflows is not slower than one that doesn't.

Comment: @FredOverflow: I see yes you are correct and I thought it was odd tomas mentioned overflows

Answer (score 0):

First, it should be noted that Andrea Alexandrescu emphasized the difference between zero and the other two good constants, that the difference between using one and negative one is less significant. He also bundles *compiler* issues with hardware issues, i.e., the hardware might be able to perform the operation efficiently but the compiler will not generate the appropriate machine code given a reasonably clear expression in the chosen higher level language.

While I cannot read his mind, there are at least two aspects that may make one better than negative one.

1. Many ISAs provide comparison operations (or flag to GPR transfers) that return zero or one (e.g., MIPS has Set on Less Than) not zero or negative one. (SIMD instructions are an exception; SIMD comparisons typically generate zero or negative one [all bits set].)
2. At least one implementation of SPARC made loading smaller signed values more expensive, and I seem to recall that at least one ISA did not provide an instruction for loading signed bytes. Naive implementation of sign extension adds latency because whether to set or clear the more significant bits is not known until the value has been loaded.

Negative one does have some benefits. As you mentioned, testing for negativity is often relatively easy, so if negative one is the only negative value used it may be handled less expensively. Also, conditionally clearing a value based on zero or negative one is simply an `and` operation. (For conditionally setting or clearing a single bit, one rather than negative one would be preferred since such would involve only a shift and an `and`.)