# why should we prefer 0 to other constant?

Tags: assembly, cpu

I watched the conference "Write quick code in C++, quickly" from A. Alexandrescu (available there https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/Writing-Quick-Code-in-Cpp-Quickly)

In this conference, Alexandrescu says (at ~28min) that we should prefer 0 as a constant because 0 is known by any cpu and that it will be handle differently.

I can understand that the compiler will genrerate faster / fewer ASM instructions but I cannot understand why it will be faster for the cpu.

I read this question [Why use 1 instead of -1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18687164/why-use-1-instead-of-1) where the OP says the 0 flag of the cpu will be set but I still don't get it (maybe the cpu will be able to skip some instructions like a multiplication with 0 ?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

processors have a zero flag which indicates the last value processed was zero, any other value needs a comparison operation first

Comment: _Some_ CPUs have a zero flag, some don't.

Comment: X86, any Arm and any other processor i have worked on has had one. I guess some may not.

Comment: MIPS and SuperH come to mind. If we're going into more obscure territory, I believe the Infineon TriCore and Toshiba MeP also did not have a zero flag. There are probably others.

Comment: What flag do you use instead?

Comment: Thanks for your answer / comments :)

Comment: @PhilWilliams: On MIPS, the `BEQ` does the comparison, and you've got a GPR that always has the value zero, so you can do e.g. `BEQ $t0,$zero,label`. IIRC the TriCore and MeP use the same approach (though the MeP had a dedicated `BEQZ` instruction). On the SuperH there's a `T`-flag that gets set if the result of a comparison was true, so you can do `CMP/EQ #0,r0` followed by `BT label` (conveniently there's a Decrement And Test instruction (`DT`) that decrements a register and sets `T` if the register became zero).

Comment: For more recent Intel out-of-order x86 implementations, certain idioms for zeroing a register are recognized at decode and handled in renaming (this removes an operation from the scheduler and execution units and can avoid using a physical register but was largely intended to provide a means of breaking dependence chains). Comparisons against zero are also easier in hardware (less than checks one bit, equal can be determined by ORing all bits (which allows greater parallelism than a subtraction), greater than checks the sign bit and whether equal).